# How do proteins perform their function

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, protein-binding, protein-interaction, bio-mechanics

I have asked a question on physics stackexchange, but was redirected here. I copy the entire question word for word. The original is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/227647/how-do-proteins-perform-their-function?noredirect=1#comment493040_227647).

---

Let's, for example, take a ribosome. It is an enzyme that is in turn just a molecule that must follow the laws of physics.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it can be looked upon as a molecular machine made up of several pieces. What exactly makes those pieces work together?

Why does the ribosome bind to a strand of RNA? Is it just the shape and electric charge or is it something more? Once the ribosome is bound to a piece of RNA, how does it move?

In a way, I'm looking for the "ghost in the machine". I'm interested in molecules in general, not just ribosomes. What is it that, on a level of single atoms, makes molecules "alive" - move, assemble a protein, etc. ?

---

PS. I'm having trouble phrasing my question, so if anything is not clear, please leave a comment and I will address it.

---

Edit 1: This is most definitely a physics question. I'm looking at the scale of several atoms.

Let me give a hypothetical example:

Imagine a strand of carbons. Also imagine that there exists a molecule that can move along this strand. How would it do it? What forces would move it along this strand? Is it electromagnetism? Would gravity be involved to a significant degree? What effect would shape have?

Does this make the question clearer?

Comment: Looking at the scale of atoms will not help understanding a molecular machine made of thousands of them.

Comment: @Chris How should I try to understand molecular machinery? What topics, books, resources should I look for?

Comment: I agree with Chris, a lot of how enzymes process things is related to their structure and the charge or lack of charge in the active site.  You also have to consider that ATP is used to catalyze many reactions, meaning you have to take a more macro look.  I'd start with Biophysics.

Comment: @Nathan do you have a suggestion for a resource to start? Maybe a textbook?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Molecular-Modeling-Simulation-Interdisciplinary-Mathematics/dp/038795404X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1452024349&sr=8-1&keywords=038795404X

Comment: @Chris `Looking at the scale of atoms will not help understanding a molecular machine made of thousands of them.` It does help, it's just really, really difficult.

Comment: @tel I'd say its like looking at a screw in a robot that puts doors on cars and trying to understand how the robot puts doors on cars.  In the reference of what a particular screw does in light of the whole, you may gain something.  But in just looking at the screw you can't understand the bigger picture.  And that's a decent analogy since the atoms will make up the amino acids, most of which (in a high number of proteins anyways) are structural and have little function in the actuation of the protein.

Comment: @tel I would say it's lloking at the atoms of a car when you want to know how it works. From the viewpoint you can only see very small parts of the machine and this will not help you with overall understanding.

Comment: @Chris Your analogy is off by about 8 orders of magnitude in terms of the relative scale. Rather, it's like looking at all of the hundreds of gears, shafts, pistons, etc that make up a car's drivetrain in order to fully understand how it works. You don't just look at each of those parts in isolation, rather you try to characterize the network of their interactions.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, the level of detail can be overwhelming, but modern science is capable of productively dealing with much of that detail. Remember that one of the ultimate goals of this type of work has always been to produce and control our own custom-made proteins. It's fiddly work. The lesson of the last 40 years of progress in this field is that the details matter, often in surprising and significant ways.

Comment: @tel So is the functioning Ribosome an extremely complex machinery. I would start by reading a standard biochemistry book, which usually has a good overview and then start going more specific.

Answer (score 2):

This question is waaaay too broad, but I'll give some short and simplified answers to the hypothetical you asked at the end. First, let's reformulate your example a little bit:

#### How does the ribosome move along a strand of RNA?

- How would it do it?

  - By hydrolyzing GTP and *somehow* coupling the free energy associated with that reaction to forward motion. Keep in mind that both ribosome and RNA are constantly undergoing random-walk Brownian motion (ie jiggling), so it's more a matter of biasing the ribosome's motion in a particular direction than it is of moving the ribosome in the first place.
- What forces would move it along this strand?

  - The current understanding of molecular biophysics, which is by no means complete, says that the primary driver of this sort of protein activity is electrostatic forces.
- Is it electromagnetism?

  - There are no electric currents, per se, so magnetism does not play a role.
- Would gravity be involved to a significant degree?

  - At these scales gravity does not have a significant effect.
- What effect would shape have?

  - Shape has an enormous effect. One of the fundamental axioms of molecular biophysics is that function follows form. The 3D configuration of those electrostatic forces I mentioned is determined in turn by the 3D configuration of the involved macromolecules.

If you want to know (a lot) more about this specific question, and if you have access to journals, check out this review: [How Should We Think About the Ribosome?](http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-biophys-050511-102314)

Comment: You write "By hydrolyzing GTP and somehow coupling the free energy". When you say somehow, do you mean to say that it is very complex process or that humanity does not know?